# Geo spatial coordinates database inside the city boundary

Tags: coordinate-system, r, geojson, data

I'm looking for geospatial data from: database, spreadsheet or anything else.

My goal is to automatically point random location into a specific city (for instance Kyoto) on a 2D map with a view from above using R and leaflet. I know how to do that in term of programming but it left me the most important part which is: the data.

I'm wondering if its exists a database that contains as much as possible geographical points (latitude/longitude) inside the boundary of a mentioned city. Like a mapping or a grid or a layer that can map a specified city in term of geographical points (lat/long).

Does anyone have some resources to achieve this goal?

Comment: You will not find a database or list of possible coordinates inside a city boundary, there are infinite points inside any polygonal area if you use enough decimal places in the coordinate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract all point (node?) from open street map for the Kyoto area.
you could easily do it with qgis and the QuickOSM plugin or use the overpass api (see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API for detail on that).

If you really want a grid of point you could get a polygon of your area, rasterise it with a cell size corresponding to the expected density of point then use a raster to point tool to get your grid of point

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple (or more options):

- Use a geocoding api (Like Google's, Bing, OpenStreetMap and others). The api retuns the coordinates (latitude, longitude).
- Use a vector dataset, like the Populated Places dataset from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/)